# Comparing elements in a list of pairs

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm having trouble figuring this function out:

> Define a function `maybeA :: [(String, a)] -> Maybe (String, a, a)` that takes a list of pairs. If the input list has two pairs `(a1, b1), (a2, b2)` such that a1 = a2, the function returns a tuple containing a1 and b1, b2. Otherwise it returns Nothing. Example: `maybeA [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("b", 3)]` will return `Just ("b", 2, 3)`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a "combinator approach" - breaking the problem into small, simple steps, and applying those steps one after the next using function composition:

```
import Data.List (sort, groupBy)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Data.Function (on)

maybeA = fmap formatAnswer . listToMaybe . dropWhile (null . drop 1) .
         groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort
  where
    formatAnswer ((a, b1):(_, b2):_) = (a, b1, b2)
```

Some notes:

- `fmap` applies a function to the value inside a `Maybe`, if it exists. (`fmap` works in a similar way on many other types, too.)
- `(==)``on`` ` fst `` tests whether two tuples are equal on their first elements.
- `sort` compares *both* elements in a tuple, but it uses dictionary order. So it works here, but it sometimes changes the order of `b1` and `b2`. If that is a problem for you,
  use `sortBy (comparing fst)` instead. `sortBy` is in the `Data.List` module, and `comparing` is in the `Data.Function` module.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the first two occurrences where two pairs have the same first two elements then the following definition will work:

```
maybeA :: [(String, a)] -> Maybe (String, a, a)
maybeA = maybeA' []
  where
    maybeA' _ []           = Nothing
    maybeA' as ((x,y):xys) = 
      case lookup x as of
        Just y' -> Just (x,y,y')
        Nothing -> maybeA' ((x,y):as) xys
```

Note, that if you pass it a list containing `(a1, b1)`, `(a2, b2)` and `(a3, b3)` where `a1` == `a2` and `a2` == `a3`, it will only return `Just (a1, b1,b2)` not `Just (a1, b1,b2,b3)` (which wouldn't even be of the same type).

Designing a function which does this is left as an exercise :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your approach should take 2 arguments, which are 2 lists right? Since maybeA' _ [] = Nothing, the type of maybeA' should be :: [(String,a)] -> [(String,a)] -> Maybe (String,a,a) right? And this will work if each list has only 1 pair. Is there any way that this function can take only 1 list of many pairs? I do appreciate your answer though :)

Comment: This is likely to be what the homework problem expects, but note that this is a pretty terrible algorithm in practice because `lookup` has to do a linear search through the list. A binary tree such as `Data.Map` would be much better.